# Calling a function from another hooked component with ref/forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-forwardref

I'm trying to call a function from another component, with the old fashion react Class style I was able to do it easily, since I'm trying to hooked everything I'm facing this kind of issue

This code doesn't work when we call setText() using the reference :

```js
export function MyComp(props, ref) {
  const [theText, setText] = useState(props.theText);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{theText}</h1>
      <button
        onClick={e => {
          setText("clicked with inside button");
        }}
      >
        inside button
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={e => {
          setText("not clicked");
        }}
      >
        reinit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export const MyRefComp = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <MyComp ref={ref} {...props}>
    {props.children}
  </MyComp>
));

function App() {
  const compref = useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <MyRefComp ref={compref} theText="not clicked" />
      <button
        onClick={e => {
          compref.current.setText("clicked with outside button");
        }}
      >
        outside button
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

here is the editable code : https://codesandbox.io/s/reactforwardrefproblem-ublk0

Thanks for helping

Comment: Is there a special reason you want to use an imperative API instead of callbacks? Usually this is considered an anti-pattern. This looks to me like a pattern to _reset_ an uncontrolled component.

Comment: I've simplified my case with that example, but if you manage to do the same result with callback, could you explain what you have in mind? I just want to call a function under another instanciated component, it's something that i've done with Class and ref, but impossible with hooks

Comment: _"I just want to call a function under another instanciated component"_. This is why I'm asking because this is not how you do it with react. There are only very few cases where this is considered a good design decision. Callbacks and lifting state up are the bread and butter of react. I just want to make sure, this is not the [X-Y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/364724) before writing a lengthy answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to your question, but i don't think it's a good pattern to do like this.

You need explain what are you trying to do, so we can help you. I assume context or HOC is what you needed.

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-0khp0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @RTW,
It's incredible how many combinaisons I tried and I didn't manange to do it.
Context or HOC won't fit in my case.
I've also simplified it to avoid the intermediaite component, and allow multiple calls with an object that contains the func.
here is it :

```js
const MyComp = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [theText, setText] = useState(props.theText);
  ref.current = { setText: setText };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{theText}</h1>
      <button
        onClick={e => {
          setText("clicked with inside button");
        }}
      >
        inside button
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={e => {
          setText("not clicked");
        }}
      >
        reinit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});

function App() {
  let compref = useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <MyComp ref={compref} theText="not clicked" />
      <button
        onClick={e => {
          compref.current.setText("clicked with outside button");
        }}
      >
        outside button
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-x194f